# Configure npm cli flags from package.json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

According to [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#color), I can use `--color` cli flag to disable colours in console, which works great from cli, but I was also expecting to be able to set it in `package.json`, but it appears to have no effect when set in there...

[image: screenshot]

p.s. I was also hoping to set `--loglevel silent` from within `package.json` too - but I expecting solving first problem will inherently solve second also.

Answer (score 9):

ok - turns out it should be in `.npmrc` and not in `.package.json` - this works as expected...

contents of `.npmrc`:

```
loglevel=silent
color=false
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. I always hated that LONG npm err message, over 30 lines. I had no idea `.npmrc` even existed. and your solution is PERFECT! Now it just says `Process finished with exit code 1` with no annoying error paragraph!

Comment: For future googlers:  "failed at the @ script this is probably not a problem with npm there is likely additional logging output above a complete log of this run can be found in".  Thank you four thousand times per second Billy Moon.